# Picking XML tag using for-each and putting values in different tags in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My XML is -

```
<doc>
<blk_customer_Details>
<custno>1010101</custno>
</blk_customer_Details>
<blk_customer_Details>
<custno>2020202</custno>
</blk_customer_Details>
<blk_customer_Details>
<custno>3030303</custno>
</blk_customer_Details>
</doc>
```

My XSLT is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <OPSC_IF_APPLICANT>
    <xsl:for-each select="blk_customer_Details">
        <xsl:variable name="counter" select="position()" />
        <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$counter = 1">
          <applicant_id><xsl:value-of select="custno"/></applicant_id>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$counter = 2">
         <applicant_id1><xsl:value-of select="custno"/></applicant_id1>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$counter = 3">
          <applicant_id2><xsl:value-of select="custno"/></applicant_id2>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </OPSC_IF_APPLICANT>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to get the following XML after applying XSLT-

```
<OPSC_IF_APPLICANT>
<applicant_id>1010101</applicant_id>
<applicant_id1>2020202</applicant_id1>
<applicant_id2>3030303</applicant_id2>
</OPSC_IF_APPLICANT>
```

I am new to XSLT. I have seen a few examples on use of position() function and my above XSLT should work. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Change <xsl:template match="/"> to <xsl:template match="doc">

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you.